# How to concatenate two layers in keras?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, hierarchical

I have an example of a neural network with two layers. The first layer takes two arguments and has one output. The second should take one argument as result of the first layer and one additional argument. It should looks like this:

```
x1  x2  x3
 \  /   /
  y1   /
   \  /
    y2
```

So, I'd created a model with two layers and tried to merge them but it returns an error: `The first layer in a Sequential model must get an "input_shape" or "batch_input_shape" argument.` on the line `result.add(merged)`.

Model:

```python
first = Sequential()
first.add(Dense(1, input_shape=(2,), activation='sigmoid'))

second = Sequential()
second.add(Dense(1, input_shape=(1,), activation='sigmoid'))

result = Sequential()
merged = Concatenate([first, second])
ada_grad = Adagrad(lr=0.1, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0)
result.add(merged)
result.compile(optimizer=ada_grad, loss=_loss_tensor, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Comment: I think this problem is known as hierarchical fusion in AI, mostly used for multimodal data.

Answer (score 145, accepted):

You're getting the error because `result` defined as `Sequential()` is just a container for the model and you have not defined an input for it.

Given what you're trying to build set `result` to take the third input `x3`.

```python
first = Sequential()
first.add(Dense(1, input_shape=(2,), activation='sigmoid'))

second = Sequential()
second.add(Dense(1, input_shape=(1,), activation='sigmoid'))

third = Sequential()
# of course you must provide the input to result which will be your x3
third.add(Dense(1, input_shape=(1,), activation='sigmoid'))

# lets say you add a few more layers to first and second.
# concatenate them
merged = Concatenate([first, second])

# then concatenate the two outputs

result = Concatenate([merged,  third])

ada_grad = Adagrad(lr=0.1, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0)

result.compile(optimizer=ada_grad, loss='binary_crossentropy',
               metrics=['accuracy'])
```

However, my preferred way of building a model that has this type of input structure would be to use the [functional api](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/).

Here is an implementation of your requirements to get you started:

```python
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Concatenate, Dense, LSTM, Input, concatenate
from keras.optimizers import Adagrad

first_input = Input(shape=(2, ))
first_dense = Dense(1, )(first_input)

second_input = Input(shape=(2, ))
second_dense = Dense(1, )(second_input)

merge_one = concatenate([first_dense, second_dense])

third_input = Input(shape=(1, ))
merge_two = concatenate([merge_one, third_input])

model = Model(inputs=[first_input, second_input, third_input], outputs=merge_two)
ada_grad = Adagrad(lr=0.1, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0)
model.compile(optimizer=ada_grad, loss='binary_crossentropy',
               metrics=['accuracy'])
```

**To answer the question in the comments:**

1. How are result and merged connected? Assuming you mean how are they concatenated.

Concatenation works like this:

```python
  a        b         c
a b c   g h i    a b c g h i
d e f   j k l    d e f j k l
```

i.e rows are just joined.

2. Now, `x1` is input to first, `x2` is input into second and `x3` input into third.

Comment: How are `result` and `merged` (or `merged2`) layers connected with each other on the first part of your answer?

Comment: and the second question. As I understand `x1` and `x2` is an input for `first_input`, `x3` for `third_input`. What's about `second_input`?

Comment: `second_input` is passed through an  `Dense` layer and is concatenated  with `first_input` which also was passed through a `Dense` layer.  `third_input` is passed through a dense layer and the concatenated with the result of the previous concatenation (`merged`)

Comment: @putonspectacles The second way using the functional API works, however, the first way using a Sequential-model is not working for me in Keras 2.0.2. I've roughly checked the implementation and calling "Concatenate([...])" does not do much and furthermore, you cannot add it to a sequential model. I actually think one still needs to use the depricated method "Merge([...], 'concat')" until they update Keras. What do you think?

Comment: I have 2 models with final layer as `Dense(number_of_sleep_stages, activation='softmax')`. What should be my input for the concatenated model? 
`merge = Concatenate([model1, model2])
final_model = Model(outputs = merge, inputs = ???)`

Comment: it should be whatever the input are for the two model. inputs= [ input1, input2]. That is the best i can do with out seeing your model.

Comment: Is there any rationale for while concatenation results in rows being merged instead of columns being merged, or depth stacking or some other way of merging that preserves their discrete inputs?

Comment: The example with the `Sequential` model indeed does not work. Is this (multi-input models) still possible with the `Sequential` API?

Comment: @sdcbr I'll have a look, not sure

Comment: There is an error in the first method "Concatenate([first, second])". Concatenate is a class not a function, so it should be Concatenate()([first, second]). An easy trap when using the classes of layers.

Comment: What is the difference between `Concatenate()` and `concatenate()` layers in Keras?

Answer (score 12):

Adding to the above-accepted answer so that it helps those who are using `tensorflow 2.0`

```py
import tensorflow as tf

# some data
c1 = tf.constant([[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2]], dtype=tf.float32)
c2 = tf.constant([[2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]], dtype=tf.float32)
c3 = tf.constant([[3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4]], dtype=tf.float32)

# bake layers x1, x2, x3
x1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)(c1)
x2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)(c2)
x3 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)(c3)

# merged layer y1
y1 = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=1)([x1, x2])

# merged layer y2
y2 = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=1)([y1, x3])

# print info
print("-"*30)
print("x1", x1.shape, "x2", x2.shape, "x3", x3.shape)
print("y1", y1.shape)
print("y2", y2.shape)
print("-"*30)
```

Result:

```
------------------------------
x1 (2, 10) x2 (2, 10) x3 (2, 10)
y1 (2, 20)
y2 (2, 30)
------------------------------
```

Answer (score 8):

You can experiment with `model.summary()` (notice the concatenate_XX (Concatenate) layer size)

```
# merge samples, two input must be same shape
inp1 = Input(shape=(10,32))
inp2 = Input(shape=(10,32))
cc1 = concatenate([inp1, inp2],axis=0) # Merge data must same row column
output = Dense(30, activation='relu')(cc1)
model = Model(inputs=[inp1, inp2], outputs=output)
model.summary()

# merge row must same column size
inp1 = Input(shape=(20,10))
inp2 = Input(shape=(32,10))
cc1 = concatenate([inp1, inp2],axis=1)
output = Dense(30, activation='relu')(cc1)
model = Model(inputs=[inp1, inp2], outputs=output)
model.summary()

# merge column must same row size
inp1 = Input(shape=(10,20))
inp2 = Input(shape=(10,32))
cc1 = concatenate([inp1, inp2],axis=1)
output = Dense(30, activation='relu')(cc1)
model = Model(inputs=[inp1, inp2], outputs=output)
model.summary()
```

You can view notebook here for detail:
https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/anhhh11/DeepLearning/blob/master/Concanate_two_layer_keras.ipynb

Comment: What is the difference between `Concatenate()` and `concatenate()` layers in Keras?

Comment: Did you figure out the difference, one is a Keras class and another is a tensorflow method