# keras: concatenate two images as input (DeepVO)

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network, opticalflow

I'm trying to implement the model described in [this paper](https://senwang.gitlab.io/DeepVO/files/wang2017DeepVO.pdf).
One item I've having trouble with is setting up the input, which is supposed to be two images stacked, meaning, I have a set of consecutive `(i & i+1)` images *2048x2048x1* (monochrome), so the input tensor would be *2048x2048x2*, but each successive input to the neural net would be the following set of images `(i+1 & i+2)`. 
So far I have

```python
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Concatenate, Activation, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Input
from keras.klayers import Embedding,LSTM 

inp1 = Input((2048,2048,1))
inp2 = Input((2048,2048,1))
deepVO = Sequential()
deepVO.add(Concatenate(inp1,inp2,-1))
deepVO.add(Conv2D(64,(2,2)))
deepVO.add(Activation('relu'))
#....continue to add other layers
```

The error I get at `deepVO_CNN.add(Concatenate(inp1,inp2,-1))` is:

> TypeError: __init__() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 4 were given.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to concatenate two layers in keras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43196636/how-to-concatenate-two-layers-in-keras)

Comment: Why? Just use `Input((2048,2048,2))` and pass both the images concatenated using numpy.

Comment: You are mixing sequential and functional APIs, don't do that. For this you can just use the functional API.

Answer (score 6):

try the keras api mode like this:

```python
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Input, concatenate

from keras.models import Model

inp1 = Input((2048,2048,1))
inp2 = Input((2048,2048,1))

deepVO = concatenate([inp1, inp2],axis=-1)
deepVO = Conv2D(64,(2,2))(deepVO)
deepVO = Activation('relu')(deepVO)
...

...
outputs = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(deepVO)
deepVO = Model([inp1, inp2], outputs)
#deepVO.summary()
```