# How to merge layers of different sizes to skip connections in tensorflow/keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am implementing the following [architecture](https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-HQo2Kx39Q6A/WsqZQn5pJHI/AAAAAAAAVhY/FBkgOeS06vQNvZN2KI2hhGZmfS1cNPg8wCLcBGAs/s1600/enasdiscoverednetwork.png) in colab using tensorflow and keras. How can I concatenate the 2 different layers of different shapes in order to facilitate the skip connections.

Thanks

Sai

Answer (score 1):

You can check [Keras merge layers](https://keras.io/layers/merge/). You can use a large number of different functions (Add, Subtract, Concatenate, ..etc.).
A good example is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43196636/how-to-concatenate-two-layers-in-keras/43196972).