# keras : add layers to another model

Tags: keras, neural-network, keras-layer, tf.keras

I need to add layers to an existing model. However, I need to add the layers at "the main model level", that is I can't use the classic functional approach. For example, if I use something like:

```
from keras.layers import Dense,Reshape, Input
inp = Input(shape=(15,))
d1 = Dense(224*224*3, activation='linear')(inp)
r1 = Reshape(input_shape)
from keras import Model
model_mod = r1(d1)
model_mod = mobilenet(model_mod)
model_mod = Model(inp, model_mod)
```

I obtain:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_5 (InputLayer)         (None, 15)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)              (None, 150528)            2408448   
_________________________________________________________________
reshape_4 (Reshape)          (None, 224, 224, 3)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
mobilenet_1.00_224 (Model)   (None, 1000)              4253864
```

So, I obtain a model with a nested submodel. Instead, I would the nested submodel's layers (mobilenet) "added" to the new top layers (that is, after reshape_4). I tried with:

```
modelB_input = modelB.input
for layer in modelB.layers:
    if layer == modelB_input:
        continue
    modelA.add(layer)
```

It works for simple sequential models (e.g., vgg, mobilenet) but with more complex models with connections not strictly sequential (e.g., inception,resnet) this code is not good.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `keras.layers.Concatenate` to merge two models like so:

```
first = Sequential()
first.add(Dense(1, input_shape=(2,), activation='sigmoid'))

second = Sequential()
second.add(Dense(1, input_shape=(1,), activation='sigmoid'))
 
merged = Concatenate([first, second])
```

(Taken from: [How to concatenate two layers in keras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43196636/how-to-concatenate-two-layers-in-keras/43196972))

Although this example uses `keras.models.Sequential`, it works for other models or layers as well.

You can also take a look at: https://keras.io/api/layers/merging_layers/concatenate/

Comment: it doesn't work. The result is a layer, not a model, so for example I can't see the result with the  `merged.summary()` because I obtain `'Concatenate' object has no attribute 'summary'`

Comment: Did you tried to instantiate a model with that resulting layer?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to add a A layer to a B layer in the existed model, you can get the B layer output to the A layer  and parse them to a new model by `tf.keras.model.Model`. An comprehensive demonstration for this method is in the feature extractor for object detection or segmentation. You can found one in [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/models/feature_map_generators.py#L258-L305)

For example by adding 2 new layers to VGG16 model at the bottom

```
full_vgg_model = tf.keras.applications.VGG16(
                            include_top=False,
                            weights="imagenet",
                            input_tensor=None,
                            input_shape=None,
                            pooling=None,
                            classes=1000,
                        )
```

The current layers:

```
Model: "vgg16"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         [(None, None, None, 3)]   0         
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 64)    1792      
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 64)    36928     
_________________________________________________________________
block1_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, None, None, 64)    0         
_________________________________________________________________
block2_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 128)   73856     
_________________________________________________________________
block2_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 128)   147584    
_________________________________________________________________
block2_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, None, None, 128)   0         
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 256)   295168    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 256)   590080    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 256)   590080    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, None, None, 256)   0         
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 512)   1180160   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 512)   2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 512)   2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, None, None, 512)   0         
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 512)   2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 512)   2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 512)   2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, None, None, 512)   0         
=================================================================
Total params: 14,714,688
Trainable params: 14,714,688
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Then I append 2 new layers:

```
conv6 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(1024, 3, strides=(1, 1), padding='same', activation='relu', dilation_rate=(6,6), name='conv6')(full_vgg_model.layers[-1].output)

conv7 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(1024, 1, strides=(1, 1), padding='same', activation='relu', name='conv7')(conv6)
    
classification_backbone = tf.keras.Model(
            inputs=full_vgg_model.inputs,
            outputs=[conv6,conv7])
```

We got them stacked at the bottom!

```
Model: "model"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         [(None, None, None, 3)]   0         
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 64)    1792      
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 64)    36928     
_________________________________________________________________
block1_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, None, None, 64)    0         
_________________________________________________________________
block2_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 128)   73856     
_________________________________________________________________
block2_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 128)   147584    
_________________________________________________________________
block2_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, None, None, 128)   0         
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 256)   295168    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 256)   590080    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 256)   590080    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, None, None, 256)   0         
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 512)   1180160   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 512)   2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 512)   2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, None, None, 512)   0         
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 512)   2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 512)   2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 512)   2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, None, None, 512)   0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv6 (Conv2D)               (None, None, None, 1024)  4719616   
_________________________________________________________________
conv7 (Conv2D)               (None, None, None, 1024)  1049600   
=================================================================
Total params: 20,483,904
Trainable params: 20,483,904
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Comment: instead of outputs=[conv6,conv7], outputs=conv7 should be enough no? It's working for me that way

Comment: ah yes, it is just for a demonstration that you can output more than 1